# Is the "ng" sound often pronounced simultaneously with the "n" sound?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, consonants

Don't native speakers in some regions pronounce [ŋ] simultaneously with the [n] sound in order to connect it without releasing the "g"?

For instance, can the word "singer" instead of **sɪŋ·ər**, be pronounced more like **sɪŋn·ər**?

I'm asking because every time I try to pronounce that word, the "g" sound is released automatically, even though it's very slight, and the only way to avoid it is adding the "n" sound.

My native language is Russian.

Comment: @Mick - but I doubt anybody would pronounce *singer* as "singNer"

Comment: @Henry Ah! IPA confuses me, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you look at the OP's use of IPA, you see that this is NOT the same question as why some accents pronounce _singer_ like _finger_, but a question from a non-native speaker about how to produce the sound.

Comment: It might help if you mention what your native language is. I haven't heard before of people hearing "singer" as [sɪŋnər]

Comment: In my fairly standard BrE dialect the word "singer" is pronounced with a slight **g** heard. It is soft. The word "finger" has a hard **g**. Both come from the tongue against the palate, but the hard **g** comes from further back in the mouth. The difference is slight, in the same way that the difference in tongue action between **d** and **t** is slight, in this case against the front teeth.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Unless you're a trained phonetician, it seems probable based on that description that you actually don't pronounce "singer" with any kind of [g] sound, but just with the velar nasal [ŋ]. This is a nasal consonant like [m] or [n], pronounced in the same place in the mouth as the sounds [k] or [g]. But phonetically, it doesn't contain the sound [g]--not even a "slight" or "soft" g--any more than [n] contains the sound [d], or [m] contains the sound [b] (compare words like "bomb" and "tomb", where the vast majority of speakers don't actually pronounce any [b] sound at the end)

Comment: My problem is, basically, that i can't connect the "ng" sound with the next sound (unless it's a stop consonant) without releasing the "g" sound.But if i pronounce the "ng" sound simultaneously with the "n" , then it's no problem.

Comment: Is it possible for you to produce [ŋ] at the start of a word, if you try? e.g. try to just say a syllable like [ŋu]

Comment: It is.I just put my tongue into the position for g/k sounds and release the air flow through my nose.But the problem is I always  automatically release the g sound

Comment: @sumelic my speaking of [m] or [n], are pronounced nowhere near in the same place in the mouth as the sounds [k] or [g]. And you have a "straw man" argument. The final [b] in **bomb** is irrelevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I was saying that [ŋ] is pronounced in the same place in the mouth as [k] and [g]. That is part of why, to many English speakers, it sounds like it contains the sound [g], even though it doesn't. It's pronounced in a different place from [m] and [n]--[m] is pronounced with both lips, [n] is pronounced somewhere around the base of the teeth and the back of the front gums--I don't remember the exact tongue contact points that are most important for its articulation--but [m] and [n] are similar to [ŋ] in that they are all nasal consonants, where the air flows through the nose

Comment: @Alex1751: well, you can pronounce [n] without releasing a [d] sound, right? So instead of starting from a [g] or [k] position and trying to nasalize that to get the [ŋ] sound, can you try starting from [n] and trying to articulate it further back in your mouth? E.g. try to say [nu], then say [ŋu], and practice moving between them until you feel more comfortable making the [ŋ] sound before a vowel

Comment: I certainly can pronounce [nu] without the d sound, but in the case of [ŋu] it's a different story :(

Comment: @Weather The final b in _tomb_ is actually not irrelevant. The reason many (probably most) native speakers will claim that they can hear a ‘soft’ or ‘weak’ [ɡ] in words like _singer_ is exactly the same reason why those same people will claim they can hear a ‘soft’ or ‘weak’ [b] in _tomb_ or a p in _psyche_: they know it’s there in writing. Their brain reconstructs a sound that isn’t actually there based on what they know the spelling looks like. When the actual sounds are put to machine-based tests, it is clear that the sound is not there.

Comment: @Alex What is your native language? There may be some trick you can use based on your own language to make this easier for you in English.

Comment: My native language is Russian

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet there is an audible difference between "sinner" and "singer". The sound of the **g** is not imaginary. I don't pronounce the **p** is "psyche" nor the final **b** in "bomb". I still say - irrelavant to "singer".

Comment: @Weather Of course there is. They are different sounds. _Sinner_ has [n]; _singer_ has [ŋ]. There is also—apart from the initial s/f difference—an audible difference between _singer_ and _finger_, which does have [ɡ]. It’s not the notion that [n] and [ŋ] are different sounds that is imaginary, but the notion that _singer_ contains the same sound as the consonant found in _go_ anywhere. It does not (except in a few dialects where _singer_ and _finger_ are in fact pronounced the same, apart from s/f). The relationship between [ŋ] and [ɡ] is the same as that between [n] and [d]: nasal vs plosive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, native English speakers do not add an extra n after the /ŋ/ in the word *singer*, though some do have the same issue as you with having difficulty producing /ŋ/ in the middle of words like *singer* and *singing.*

The "ng" sound in medial and final word position can be challenging for native Russian speakers.  What's happening is that /ŋ/ is a continuant sound, and if you release the tongue from the sealed position for the /ŋ/ while you are still producing airflow, you will make a /g/ or /k/ sound because the release of the built-up air produces the sound.

The way to avoid this problem is to begin to shape the vowel for the *"-er"* before releasing the /ŋ/ tongue position, and to release the tongue gently into the vowel.  If no air is allowed to build up, the plosive/stop g sound will not be produced.

You can hear the pronunciation of *singer* in this video: https://youtu.be/c-3HtmE5muY
and get more information about the /ŋ/ phoneme in American English in this video: https://youtu.be/-DZ5GICTHVU

I will be making a more specific video to help with words with "-nger" and "-inging" in the future, as I have heard from many Russian and other non-native speakers that these are particularly difficult to make without the "g" sound intruding.  I'll add it to this post as an edit when it's complete.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly certain "ng" sounds are always pronounced together.  That being said, there would be certain dialects that add in a hard "g" sound but personally I never hear it.

I think the "er" sound at the end causes some dialects to pronounce the "g", but if you didn't have "er", the world "sing" would be simple and never have a hard "g" sound.

Comment: I am pretty certain that Professor Brian Cox, who is from Oldham, Lancashire, England, uses this pronunciation.

Comment: This isn’t actually what the question is asking about. The question is about adding an extra /n/, not an extra /ɡ/ (that’s what the other question, the one this has erroneously been marked a duplicate of, is about, but not this one).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - or is it about moving from a velar nasal to an alveolar nasal? as in the questions https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59653/ing-vs-in-ending and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71255/when-does-realisation-of-velar-nasal-%c5%8b-as-alveolar-nasal-n-happen-along-with